# monitoring a node.js server

Tags: node.js

I am looking for a way to get some sort of monitoring, statistic or management data out of a node.js server instance - not sure what to search for or where to start. Any advice appreciated.

Stats would be requests processed (if applicable) - number of connections and so on.

Comment: basics: http://oguzbastemur.blogspot.com/2014/05/monitoring-nodejs-applications-using.html It also provides monitoring information as a JSON data file on the fly.

Comment: Have a try of https://keymetrics.io/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Don't know if it will fit your needs, but you can try to look at [node-monitor](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-monitor). Also Joyent is doing some advanced real-time performance [analysis](http://wiki.joyent.com/wiki/display/sdc/Using+Cloud+Analytics) stuff, but it's probably only for their cloud services.

Comment: Thanks - yes as part of a larger setup you can get stats from proxies etc - but that node-monitor thing looks simple and handy to wire in.

Comment: Node-monitor is amazing. You can also try out [Atatus APM](https://www.atatus.com/application-monitoring/overview) which provides deeper visibility into your Node.js app performance and errors.

*PS: I work at Atatus*

Answer (score 12):

[Nodetime](http://nodetime.com) can monitor different metrics, such as HTTP Response time, CPU time, OS Load, etc. It is also possible to set up email Alerts based on these metrics. More in the blog post [Monitoring Node.js Application Performance](http://nodetime.com/blog/monitoring-nodejs-application-performance).