# Measuring and monitoring Node.JS server performance

Tags: node.js

I'm new to Node.JS, already Googled for aswers but there is a lot of ways of doing this.
Do you have some sort of math to know when I'll need to scale my Node.JS server? And what tools you use for monitoring server performance and error track?

Thanks!

Comment: What about "if it's too slow"? You need to know for yourself if your system becomes so slow that you need to scale it e.g. by adding more servers. No math can answer that for you - for some people/apps high performance is much more needed than for others.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As @ThiefMaster said, this depends on your system. You need to monitor the requests for your site, the CPU load, memory footprint etc and decide if and when to add mode servers.

If you want to know more about Node.js performance read this good article: http://blog.3rd-eden.com/post/5809079469/theoretical-node-js-real-time-performance

If you need a Node.js metrics library, there are 2 ones which I can recommend: 
 https://github.com/felixge/node-measured 
https://github.com/mikejihbe/metrics

Resources:

[monitoring a node.js server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580776/monitoring-a-node-js-server)

Comment: **First:** You can try  [node-monitor](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-monitor) which provides basic level monitoring. **Second:** If you want to test your node.js app performance during development, then you can try [Nodejs Dashboard](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/nodejs-dashboard). **Third:** If you want to monitor your app in production(in real-time) and to get deep insights, you can checkout [Atatus APM](https://www.atatus.com/application-monitoring/overview) which helps you to monitor both performance and error in your Node.js apps.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend monitoring your event loop and if it starts to back up more than 200ms on a regular basis, you'll need to scale.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: @DaveW awesome idea! could you supply a script?